# I changed my steering column on my ML320 and I can't get it to start

Tags: mercedes-benz, ignition-key, ml320

I have a 2001 ML320 I have changed out the steering column because I was told I could not change out the tumblers. Without my consent the locksmith pulled out my old column and I went and got one from Pick-n-Pull and put it in. Unfortunately this is the third steering column this car has had. When I bought the car I did not know this. I bought this car from Pick-n-Pull they did not tell me that they had changed the steering column. When the locksmith pulled out the old column he found two key fobs behind the dash. The key I had for the car at that time would unlock the driver side door and start the car but since,I have lost it and I'm now

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  So, just wondering ... what exactly is your question? MB doesn't play with reusing keys, so I'm sure that extends to the column with already used keys. Only way to make it work (from my understanding) is to buy new keys from MB which match your VIN.